# Get value from a Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have this customTextFormField that I use for the register_page and my login_page. To improve performance I extract it out into a statefulWidget. So I want to be able to access the _controller of each customFormField so I can get the _controller.text and use it to store value in local storage.

```
class CustomTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextFormField(
      {super.key,
      required this.hint,
      required this.inputType,
      required this.regExp});

  final String hint;
  final TextInputType inputType;
  final RegExp regExp;
  
  @override
  State<CustomTextFormField> createState() => _CustomTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: widget.hint,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
          controller: _controller,
          keyboardType: widget.inputType,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return "Field can not be empty";
            }
            if (widget.regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
              return "Field has invalid value";
            }
            return null;
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

The register page, here I am going to add shared_preferences that I want to use to save a the user class.

```
class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomTextFormField(
                    hint: 'Username',
                    inputType: TextInputType.name,
                    regExp: RegExpControl.userNameRegExp),
                CustomTextFormField(
                    hint: 'Phone number',
                    inputType: TextInputType.phone,
                    regExp: RegExpControl.phoneNumRegExp),
                const PasswordChecking(),
                MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  onPressed: () {
                    _formKey.currentState!.validate()
                        ? Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            context, NamedRoute.homePageName, (route) => false)
                        : Dialogs.alert(context, "Err", 'ERRR');
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Register",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, NamedRoute.loginPageName, (route) => false);
                    },
                    child: const Text("Have an account ? Login"))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My user class

```
class User {
  String phoneNum;
  String email;
  String userName;
  String passWord;

  User({
    required this.phoneNum,
    required this.email,
    required this.userName,
    required this.passWord,
  });

  User.formJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : phoneNum = json['phoneNum'],
        email = json['email'],
        userName = json['userName'],
        passWord = json['passWord'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring the `TextEditingController` in the `CustomTextFormField`, you should pass it from the parent widget. Then you can access its value and/or manipulate it as needed.

```html
class CustomTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextFormField(
      {super.key,
      required this.controller,   <--- add controler
      required this.hint,
      required this.inputType,
      required this.regExp});

  final String hint;
  final TextInputType inputType;
  final RegExp regExp;
  final TextEditingController controller;    <--- add controler
  
  @override
  State<CustomTextFormField> createState() => _CustomTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  late final TextEditingController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = widget.controller;    <--- assign controler
  }
  ...
```

The parent widget should pass the `TextEditingController` as:

```html
class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  final usernameCtrl = TextEditingController();   <--- declare controllers
  final phoneCtrl = TextEditingController();
  
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    usernameCtrl.dispose(); <--- dispose controllers
    phoneCtrl.dispose();
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomTextFormField(
                    hint: 'Username',
                    controller: usernameCtrl   <----- add controller
                    inputType: TextInputType.name,
                    regExp: RegExpControl.userNameRegExp),
                CustomTextFormField(
                    hint: 'Phone number',
                    controller: phoneCtrl   <----- add controller
                    inputType: TextInputType.phone,
                    regExp: RegExpControl.phoneNumRegExp),
                const PasswordChecking(),
                MaterialButton(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                      print(usernameCtrl.text());
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            context, NamedRoute.homePageName, (route) => false);
                    }else{
                      Dialogs.alert(context, "Err", 'ERRR');
                     }
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Register",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, NamedRoute.loginPageName, (route) => false);
                    },
                    child: const Text("Have an account ? Login"))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it affect the performance in any way ?

Comment: It won't affect the app performance